# Cast/Convert a varchar as a date only if it is a full date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with a legacy database so a user can enter a full date in three separate textboxes (Day, Month, Year). Validation allows the following combinations: Day, Month, Year - Month, Year - Year. If Day, Month, Year is entered all well and good for casting/converting and comparing against another full date. If NULL then '999' should be returned. If just Month, Year or Year has been entered then is there a way to avoid varchar to date casting errors in a select statement like this?

```
SELECT 
ID,
CASE 
WHEN UserSelectedMonth IS NULL AND UserSelectedYear IS NULL THEN '999'
WHEN UserSelectedDay IS NULL AND UserSelectedMonth IS NOT NULL AND UserSelectedYear IS NOT 
NULL THEN '01/'+ UserSelectedMonth + '/' + UserSelectedYear
WHEN UserSelectedDay IS NOT NULL AND UserSelectedMonth IS NOT NULL AND UserSelectedYear IS NOT 
NULL THEN UserSelectedDay + '/' + UserSelectedMonth + '/' + UserSelectedYear 
ELSE '999'
END AS UserSelectedDate 
FROM ThisTable WHERE
(UserSelectedDate IS NOT NULL AND LEN(UserSelectedDate) = 10 AND UserSelectedDate <= 
CAST(AnotherSelectedFullDate AS Date))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`? *Assuming* (as we don't have sample data) that your day, month, and year columns are fixed width zero prefixed values, then you could easily turn them into the ISO format, which would just mean you would get `NULL` values for "dates" like `'20210231'` or `'20171904'`:

```sql
TRY_CONVERT(date,CONCAT(YearColumn,MonthColumn,DayColumn))
```

You could, if you wanted, also add the explicit style code, 112, to the above, to denote to SQL Server that the value *must* be in the format `yyyyMMdd` to be converted.

Comment: thanks, worked like a dream, annoyingly I have used that before but didn't think of it! Doh!